# GetLastError race in Asynchronous Procedure Call

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, asynchronous

Say I am using an APC where the procedure and the calling code both use SetLastError and GetLastError. This is resulting in unpredictable values from GetLastError. Is there any way out of this ?

```
VOID CALLBACK MyFunction(ULONG_PTR param)
{

    SetLastError(1);
    // Doing some stuff here which takes some time
    // Expecting 1 but can I/should I get 0 here ?
    printf("LastError: %d\n", GetLastError());    
}

int APCtry()
{

    SetLastError(0);

    DWORD dummy = 0;

    if (!QueueUserAPC(MyFunction, GetCurrentThread(), dummy))
    {
        return 0;
    }      

    printf("LastError: %d\n", GetLastError());

    SleepEx(100, TRUE);

    //SetLastError(0); Edited and commented

    printf("LastError: %d\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use SetLastError and GetLastError. Define an application-specific error reporting mechanism.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The [MSDN documentation for `GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states the value is thread-specific: *Retrieves the calling thread's last-error code value. The last-error code is maintained on a per-thread basis. Multiple threads do not overwrite each other's last-error code.*  I'd say the question needs a lot more data.  There's certainly no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) presented.

Comment: I removed the language tags since this is conceptual, and you offered no code. However, I suspect that providing code would probably help you to get more specific responses.

Comment: Well, self-inflicted.  Don't ignore the return value of SleepEx(), if you get WAIT_IO_COMPLETION and the thread doesn't otherwise do anything async then you know that the APC ran and that you can safely use GetLastError().

Comment: Donno why I got a -1. Anyway. Thanks Hans - but the GetLastError I am concerned about is within MyFunction which gets its value from the last error being set (directly or also possible indirectly) within APCtry because APCtry has already gone ahead after MyFunction started doing the time consuming part... Do you get me ?

Comment: @RbMm The initial post - in its entirety - was: *Say I am using an APC where the procedure and the calling code both use SetLastError and GetLastError. This is resulting in unpredictable values from GetLastError. Is there any way out of this ?*  Please refer to [the edit history of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39077198/revisions)

Comment: @AndrewHenle - sorry - i not view initial variant. in this case you right - was no enough info initially

Comment: Still not enough information.  What do you expect this code to do, and what does it actually do?  There's definitely no race condition here, since it is all a single thread.

Comment: @Hans: I'm not sure the last error code will *necessarily* be preserved anyway; is it documented anywhere that SleepEx() won't ever set the last error code itself?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - right - SleepEx can and should probably set the last error code - I was trying to do it manually - not needed. Whatever, if the SleepEx is for 100 milliseconds and my time costly operation within APC runs more than that time -  then what happens to the Last Error within the APC ?

Comment: @Run2 SleepEx not call SetLastError. if you Sleep in alertable state - wait will be breaked just user APC inserted to thread (in your case - APC inserted before - you will be not wait at all). but SleepEx not finished until MyFunction not finished. independent from time. if say MyFunction hung of go to infinite loop - SleepEx never return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always should have 1 as LastError in MyFunction.

> APCtry has already gone ahead after MyFunction started doing the time
>   consuming part...

This is big confusion: all of your code is executing in single thread!

```
SleepEx begin...
MyFunction...
SleepEx return
SetLastError(0); in APCtry()
```

So SleepEx does not return until MyFunction is complete. So what you set as last error after `SleepEx` (or what set SleepEx) - cannot have any effect on `MyFunction` - because all this will be only after `MyFunction` exits. What you set as last error in `MyFunction` - this you must and get here

**EDIT**

for more clarity look what is going inside SleepEx:
[image]

Comment: Wanted to edit this answer in the first place but I can't even understand it all...

Comment: @LBes - what here you not understand ? i say that `MyFunction` execute inside `SleepEx` call. so 'APCtry has already gone ahead after `MyFunction `started doing the time consuming part..' - absolute mistaken. and no any problem or race in using Get/Set LastError

Comment: i'm talking about language here. For instance in your comment: "what is it here that you do not understand"... I am aware English is not everyone's native language (it's actually not mine either), but some minimal efforts should be made to give an understandable answer. That being said, I'm not saying that your answer is not good. I'm not talking about the content but the format

Comment: @LBes - sorry for my language and thank for edit - now really much better. i also add image for clarity

Comment: sure no problem. Not sure what you mean by "mast" in your last sentence though so I left this one as it was. Upvote for the additional image.

Comment: @LBes - "mast" - i mean "must"

Comment: @LBes - right - SleepEx will not return till my APC finishes but if the SleepEx is for 100 milliseconds and my time costly operation within APC runs more than that time - then can there be a race (OK - not a race - but a inconsistency) in Last Error ? (so can the Last Error be set to 0 after 100 milliseconds ? I am seeing some such inconsistency sometimes)

Comment: @Run2 - will be no any inconsistency here. "so can the Last Error be set to 0 after 100 milliseconds " - of course no. you simply not exit from SleepEx even after 1 hour if MyFunction will be executed 1+ hour

Comment: Thanks @LBes - let me try and see if I can replicate the issue and then I will come back and accept the answer.

Comment: If the last error code is being changed while MyFunction is running, it is because something in MyFunction is changing it.  Presumably the bit of code you've described as "doing some stuff here". :-)

Comment: Accepted. The LastError value did not change for the main thread going ahead. Thanks for all the comments